# AttributeError: 'Trivia' object has no attribute 'all_answers'

Tags: python, class, oop

So im making a trivia game, but when I call the method I get an "AttributeError: 'Trivia' object has no attribute 'all_answers'". I want it to print the answers/questions etc but I get an attribute error. I have also tried redoing my indentation, but to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

```
import urllib.request
import json
import html
import random



class Trivia:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&token=0df3b13c1e3961940cfc31352d6ef84aeb140dd8cc48388e84060855713ab982"
        self.openUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(self.url)
        self.data = json.load(self.openUrl)  # opening the json data

        for item in self.data["results"]:
            self.category = html.unescape(item["category"])
            self.question = html.unescape(item["question"])
            self.correct_answer = html.unescape(item["correct_answer"])
            self.incorrect_answers = html.unescape(item["incorrect_answers"])
            self.all_answers = html.unescape(item["incorrect_answers"])
            self.all_answers.insert(random.randint(0, len(self.incorrect_answers)), self.correct_answer)


    def return_category(self):
        return self.category

    def return_question(self):
        return self.question

    def return_correct_answer(self):
        return self.correct_answer

    def return_wrong_answers(self):
        return ", ".join(self.incorrect_answers)

    def return_all_answers(self):
        print(self.all_answers)
        return self.all_answers

t = Trivia()
print(t.return_all_answers())
```

Comment: `self.data["results"]` is probably empty, so the loop `for item in self.data["results"]:` never executes and `self.all_answers` is never defined.

Answer (score 0):

My output with a print:

```
{'response_code': 3, 'results': []}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nagyl\Desktop\Prog\test.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(t.return_all_answers())
  File "C:\Users\nagyl\Desktop\Prog\test.py", line 37, in return_all_answers
    print(self.all_answers)
AttributeError: 'Trivia' object has no attribute 'all_answers'
```

Your results array is empty, therefore `all answers` isn't created. In fact, all your variables are not created. Check your API call, or declare your variables, with initial values.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was: it was the url. I guess I accidentally removed some characters. Thanks for the help